# How to replace text in div using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to take out text in a div, and replace it.

```
h2{content:none;}

h2:after{content:'CONTENT';}
```

I tried using text-indent, display:none, etc. Nothing is working. And no, I don't want to replace it with a picture. Please help, thanks.

Comment: i dont get it , please clarify the question

Comment: show HTML in question as well please

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="bla">Hello world</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bla:before {
   content: "Goodbye planet";
   position:absolute;
   background-color:white;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FHnks/1/**

Note that content added via CSS is not a part of the DOM and will not be accessible via scripts.